# How to run Native Messaging example on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: chrome-native-messaging, microsoft-edge-extension

I want to run [SecureInput](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/SecureInput) example but after I built and deployed NativeMessagingInProcess project, Extension loaded on Edge but secureinput.html file don't load content.js file. And, I checked on regedit, nothing isn't added. Did I do anything wrong? This's very different from Chrome and Firefox Native messaging extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you hosted secureinput.html in a web server? Have you run it on Windows 10 insider preview build? According to [Microsoft Edge extension API roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/extension-api-roadmap), Native Messaging APIs are supported only on build 15002 and above version.

Comment: Oh, I'm using Windows 10 Anniversary. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess Native messaging works with using desktop bridge in window 10 anniversary, if you have window creators then desktop bridge wont be required. please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge Native messaging doesn't work in window 10 anniversary, the Native messaging APIs are not available until Window 10 Creators Update(15063). The desktop bridge is only needed when UWP app cannot meet your requirements.