# Native messaging in window 10 anniversary edge browser

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Is native messaging possible in window 10 anniversary edge browser. With anniversary update, edge supports extension. I cloned secureInput edge extension from GitHub that uses native messaging but it is not working in window 10 anniversary.

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/SecureInput

please let me know the steps to make it run if it is possible to run in window 10 anniversary but If it needs window 10 creators, we need to wait for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Native Messaging example on Microsoft Edge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970865/how-to-run-native-messaging-example-on-microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 0):

As per the API Roadmap page in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/extension-api-roadmap), native messaging is supported in build 15002 and later. As a result, you'll be able to use native messaging in the Creators Update, or you can sign up for Windows Insider Preview builds (https://insider.windows.com) to get it early.

For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/native-messaging